# Complex aggregation

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I have data in a topic that needs to be counted at multiple levels and all code and articles only mention the word count example.

An example of the data would be:

serial: 123
country: us
date: 01/05/2018
state: new york
city: nyc
visitors: 5

serial: 123
country: us
date: 01/06/2018
state: new york
city: queens
visitors: 10

serial: 456
date: 01/06/2018
country: us
state: new york
city: queens
visitors: 27

serial: 123
date: 01/06/2018
country: us
state: new york
city: nyc
visitors: 867

I have done the filter, groupBy but the aggregate ?
Sorry for the Java 8 and & mix , i prefer 8 but learning it at the same time

```
KTable<String, CountryVisitorModel> countryStream1 = inStream
    .filter((key, value) -> value.status.equalsIgnoreCase("TEST_DATA"))
    .groupBy((key, value) -> value.serial)
    .aggregate(
            new Initializer<CountryVisitorModel>() {

            public CountryVisitorModelapply() {
                return new CountryVisitorModel();
            }
        },
        new Aggregator<String, InputModel, CountryVisitorModel>() {

            @Override
            public CountryVisitorModelapply(String key, InputModel value, CountryVisitorModel aggregate) {

    aggregate.serial = value.serial;
    aggregate.country_name = value.country_name;
    aggregate.city_name = value.city_name;

    aggregate.country_count++;
    aggregate.city_count++;
    aggregate.ip_count++;

        //
    return aggregate;
       }
},
Materialized.with(stringSerde, visitorSerde));
```

For all equal serial_id (this would be the group by) 
count total number of visitors per this:

serial country state city total_num_visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each record contributes to exactly one count, I would recommend to `branch()` the stream and count per sub-stream:

```java
KStream stream = builder.stream(...)
KStream[] subStreams = stream.branch(...);

// each record of `stream` will be contained in exactly _one_ `substream`
subStream[0].grouByKey().count(); // or aggregate() instead of count()
subStream[1].grouByKey().count();
// ...
```

If branching does not work, because a single record needs to go into multiple counts, you can "broadcast" and filter:

```java
KStream stream = builder.stream(...)

// each record in `stream` will be "duplicated" and sent to all `filters`
stream.filter(...).grouByKey().count(); // or aggregate() instead of count()
stream.filter(...).grouByKey().count();
// ...
```

Using the same `KStream` object multiple time and apply multiple operators (in our case `filter()`, each record will be "broadcasted" to all operators). Note, that record (ie, objects) are not physically copied for this case, but the same input record object is used to call each `filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the field values in a set and get the count per key with the Set#size method.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Grouped;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class SomeTest {

    public static class VisitorDetails {
        public long serial;
        public String country;
        public long date;
        public String state;
        public String city;
        public long visitors;
    }

    public static class Aggregate {
        public Set <String> countrySet = new HashSet <>();
        public long countryCounter;

        public Set <String> citySet = new HashSet <>();
        public long cityCounter;

        public long totalVisitorCounter = 0;
    }

    public static class CustomSerializer<T> implements Serializer <T> {
        private static final Charset CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        static private final Gson gson = new Gson();


        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
            String line = gson.toJson(data);
            return line.getBytes(CHARSET);
        }
    }

    public static class CustomDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer <T> {
        private static final Charset CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        static private final Gson gson = new Gson();

        private final Class <T> tClass;

        public CustomDeserializer(Class <T> tClass) {
            this.tClass = tClass;
        }

        @Override
        public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
            try {
                String person = new String(data, CHARSET);
                return gson.fromJson(person, tClass);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Deserialization failed:", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class AggregateSerde implements Serde <Aggregate> {

        @Override
        public Serializer <Aggregate> serializer() {
            return new CustomSerializer <Aggregate>();
        }

        @Override
        public Deserializer <Aggregate> deserializer() {
            return new CustomDeserializer <Aggregate>(Aggregate.class);
        }
    }

    public static class VisitorDetailsSerde implements Serde <VisitorDetails> {

        @Override
        public Serializer <VisitorDetails> serializer() {
            return new CustomSerializer <VisitorDetails>();
        }

        @Override
        public Deserializer <VisitorDetails> deserializer() {
            return new CustomDeserializer <VisitorDetails>(VisitorDetails.class);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test() {

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        builder.stream("input", Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), new VisitorDetailsSerde()))
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.Long(), new VisitorDetailsSerde()))
                .aggregate(
                        Aggregate::new,
                        (key, value, agg) -> {

                            agg.countrySet.add(value.country);
                            agg.countryCounter = agg.countrySet.size();

                            agg.citySet.add(value.city);
                            agg.cityCounter = agg.citySet.size();

                            agg.totalVisitorCounter += value.visitors;
                            return agg;

                        },
                        Materialized. <Long, Aggregate, KeyValueStore <Bytes, byte[]>>as("store-name-2")
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.Long())
                                .withValueSerde(new AggregateSerde())
                                .withLoggingDisabled() // only for testing,
                                // recommended to not disable on prod as it provides fault tolerance

                );

        Topology topology = builder.build();
        
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy:1234");

        TopologyTestDriver testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, properties);

        TestInputTopic <Long, VisitorDetails> inputTopic = testDriver.createInputTopic("input",
                Serdes.Long().serializer(), new CustomSerializer <VisitorDetails>());

        inputTopic.pipeInput(123L, visitorDetail(123L, "usa", "ny", 10L));
        inputTopic.pipeInput(123L, visitorDetail(123L, "usa", "la", 20L));
        inputTopic.pipeInput(123L, visitorDetail(123L, "pl", "krk", 30L));
        inputTopic.pipeInput(123L, visitorDetail(123L, "pl", "wrs", 40L));
        inputTopic.pipeInput(123L, visitorDetail(123L, "pl", "krk", 50L));

        testDriver.getAllStateStores();
        KeyValueStore <Long, Aggregate> keyValueStore = testDriver. <Long, Aggregate>getKeyValueStore("store-name-2");

        assertThat(keyValueStore.get(123L).cityCounter).isEqualTo(4);
        assertThat(keyValueStore.get(123L).countryCounter).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(keyValueStore.get(123L).totalVisitorCounter).isEqualTo(150);

        testDriver.close();

    }

    private VisitorDetails visitorDetail(long serial, String country, String city, long visitors) {
        VisitorDetails visitorDetails = new VisitorDetails();
        visitorDetails.serial = serial;
        visitorDetails.country = country;
        visitorDetails.city = city;
        visitorDetails.visitors = visitors;
        return visitorDetails;
    }
}
```